# First column offset when adding margin in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple calendar in HTML and CSS. Problem is, my  first day of the week seems to be offset and I don't know what's going on. I've inspected the elements and they all seem to be identical in the dev tools.

I've pinpointed it down and I think the culprit might be the margin of `.day`. When I delete that, everything seems to be aligned. But I have no idea why or how to fix it.

Help would me much appreciated, I'm still a newbie in CSS.

```css
.day {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-color: darkred;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: white;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  margin: 5px;
}

.week {
  column-count: 7;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1> Hello world!</h1>
<div class="week">
  <div class="day"> 3 </div>
  <div class="day"> 4 </div>
  <div class="day"> 5 </div>
  <div class="day"> 6 </div>
  <div class="day"> 7 </div>
  <div class="day"> 8 </div>
  <div class="day"> 9 </div>
</div>
<div class="week">
  <div class="day"> 3 </div>
  <div class="day"> 4 </div>
  <div class="day"> 5 </div>
  <div class="day"> 6 </div>
  <div class="day"> 7 </div>
  <div class="day"> 8 </div>
  <div class="day"> 9 </div>
</div>
```

**Here's what it looks like**
[image]

Comment: @mister-jojo That is so cool! I didn't know you can do that. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will work for you.

```css
.day {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
  color: white;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.day:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
}

.week {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1> Hello world!</h1>
<div class="week">
  <div class="day"> 3 </div>
  <div class="day"> 4 </div>
  <div class="day"> 5 </div>
  <div class="day"> 6 </div>
  <div class="day"> 7 </div>
  <div class="day"> 8 </div>
  <div class="day"> 9 </div>
</div>
<div class="week">
  <div class="day"> 3 </div>
  <div class="day"> 4 </div>
  <div class="day"> 5 </div>
  <div class="day"> 6 </div>
  <div class="day"> 7 </div>
  <div class="day"> 8 </div>
  <div class="day"> 9 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This works, thank you. Do you happen to know why my original code had that offsetting behavior?

Comment: I guess it's because the "column" property behaves this way with the "display: block;". Because if you change "display: blokc;" to "display: -webkit-box;",you will get the result that you expected.